# How to fill a div with new content using highslide ajax

Tags: highslide

I have some buttons with onclick events with purpose to load different content and display them in a content div. In highslide, I have only found the example which popups the content,
but I want to fill a div with the result.

Can you explain me how to proceed?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using AJAX? If yes, here is an example:

```
<a href="your/path/to/ajax" 
   onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this, { 
                objectType: 'ajax', 
                width: 400, 
                creditsPosition: 'bottom left',
                headingText: 'Title from onclick', 
                wrapperClassName: 'titlebar' 
            })">
    Click me!
</a>
```